# Chart.js working with database arrays and data structures

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I'm making a chart which is drawing data from a database array. I have 2 arrays:

```js
    const numPostPerCat= <?php echo json_encode($countCateT); ?>;
    const catName= <?php echo json_encode($cateTforChart); ?>;
```

Which I use to feed the chart in the traditional way:

```js
    const data2= {
        labels: catName,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Terri',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(166,166,166)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(166,166,166)',
                data: numPostPerCat,
                borderWidth: 2,
                barThickness: 3,
                datalabels: {
                    color:'gray',
                    anchor: 'end',
                    align: 'top',
                },
            }],
        };
     const config2={
        type: 'bar',
    
        data: data2,
        options: {
     
            scales: {
    
                x:{
                    grid:{
                        display: false,
                    },
                },
                y:{
                    ticks:{
                        display: false,
                        },
                        grid:{
                            display: false,
                        },
                    },
                    
                },
                
            
            plugins:{
                
                 legend: {
                   display: false
                         },
                 title:{
                     display: true,
                     text: 'Territorios',
                     align: 'start',
                 },
                                 },
            responsive: true,   
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            }
        };
        
    const myChart2 = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart2'),
        config2
    );
```

But how can I use database arrays when I want to use data structure? Should I use a different kind of a array? There's another configuration in JS? because this doesn't work:

```js
     const data2= {

     datasets: [{
                        label: 'Terri',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(166,166,166)',
                        borderColor: 'rgb(166,166,166)',
                        data: [
                       {Terris: catName, cuantos: {cantidad: numPostPerCat} 
                        },
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        barThickness: 3,
                        datalabels: {
                            color:'gray',
                            anchor: 'end',
                            align: 'top',
                        },
                    }]
                };
    
    const config2={
        type: 'bar',
    
        data: data2,
    
        options: {
            parsing:{
                    xAxisKey: 'Terris',
                    yAxisKey: 'cuantos.cantidad',
            },
            scales: {
    
                
                x:{
                    grid:{
                        display: false,
                    },
                },
                    y:{
                        ticks:{
                            display: false,
                        },
                        grid: {
                            display: false,
                        },
                    },
                    
                },
                
            
            plugins:{
                 legend: {
                   display: false
                         },
                 title:{
                     display: true,
                     text: 'Años',
                     align: 'start',
                 },
                                 },
                
            responsive: true,   
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            
    
            }
    
            };
    
    const myChart2 = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart2'),
        config2
    );
```